# Linq search by differents values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like this:

```
class Person
{
    private String sName;
    private String sPhone;
    private String sAge;
    private String sE_Mail;
    // … code …
}
```

And I have to make a search by the value received from the user, it could be, any attribute of this class. I have this too:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> SearchByPhone(string value)
{
    return from person in personCollection                   
           where person.**SPhone** == value
           select person;
}
```

I have four methods like this, the only difference is the attribute. Please, can anybody tell me how can I do this in just one method or isn't possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to write separate methods. A single method would be enough:

```
public IEnumerable<Person> Search<T>(T value, Func<Person,T> mapFunc)
{
    return from person in personCollection                   
           where mapFunc(person).Equals(value)
           select person;
 }
```

Then call it this way:

```
Search("SOME VALUE", input=>input.sPhone);  //sPhone must be public
Search("SOME VALUE", input=>input.sAge);     //sAge must be public
```

Comment: you could even switch the string's there to T, and make it generic and work for anything

Comment: This won't work for linq-to-sql. Change the signature to accept `Express<Func<Person, string>>`, and the body to do a `.Where`.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad unfortunately, that still won't work in Linq-to-Sql / Entities.

Comment: I changed this line ´SearchByPhone <string> ("SOME VALUE", input => input.sPhone);´

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [dynamic linq library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) for this

```
public IQueryable<Person> Search(string column, string value)
{
    return personCollection.Where(string.Format("{0} = @1", column), value);
}
```

Or you could build the expressions yourself:

```
public IQueryable<Person> Search(string column, string value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, column);
    var val = Expression.Constant(value, prop.Type);
    var equals = Expression.Equal(prop, val);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(equals, param);
    return personCollection.Where(lambda);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would to be to make the where statement into an or operation.

```
public IEnumerable<Person> SearchByValue(string value)
{
    return from person in personCollection
           where (person.sName.Equals(value) || 
               person.sPhone.Equals(value) || person.sAge.Equals(value) || 
               person.sE_Mail.Equals(value));
}
```

personally I prefer using the fluent api as it's less verbose and makes chaining LINQ commands together a little more obvious...here's that implementation as well

```
public IEnumerable<Person> SearchByValue(string value)
{
    return personCollection.Where(p => p.sName.Equals(value) || 
               p.sPhone.Equals(value) || p.sAge.Equals(value) || 
               p.sE_Mail.Equals(value));
}
```